# How to make all Windows network interfaces visible (and usable ) in WSL2?

Tags: networking, windows, network-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nat

I'm a student, I'm currently working on a project with the goal of integrating MultiPath TCP (MTCP) into WSL2. However, there's a significant challenge we're facing: WSL2 only exposes a single "main" network interface, which is insufficient for MTCP's optimal operation. Even if I recompile the kernel and enable MTCP, it won't function as intended because it requires multiple interfaces. My question is, what are your thoughts on the proposed network architecture to enable MTCP, are there simpler ways to do it or what could be improved? Thanks you in advance and have a nice day :)

Here's the architecture breakdown:

**Server App (In Windows):**

- *Interface Monitor*: This component monitors network interfaces. The client periodically requests the list of interfaces from the server, and based on this information, adds or removes interfaces. Alternatively, the server can write this information to a file in the WSL filesystem, which the client reads to update its interfaces.
- *Reception of Packets from TAP Interfaces*: After the client creates a TAP interface, the server spawns a thread responsible for receiving packets. The client is informed of the appropriate port for sending packets through interface updates. Each TAP interface corresponds to a dedicated port.
- *NATing Packets*: Within the thread handling packet reception, the server performs Network Address Translation (NAT) by modifying relevant IP fields. This operation can be facilitated using a library like PcapPlusPlus, which simplifies TCP packet modification.
- *Sending Packets*: Some threads on StackOverflow have suggested that Windows restricts the direct sending of raw packets. I'm still exploring options for sending data directly to the respective interface.

**Client App (In WSL2):**

- *TAP Interface Creation*: The client reacts to interface updates by creating or removing TAP interfaces accordingly.
- *Interface Listening*: Once a TAP interface is created, the client uses a library called libpcap to sniff packets from it.
- *Sending Packets via UDP*: Each interface is associated with a dedicated port to ensure the correct transmission of captured packets.
- *Receiving Response*: A thread will be responsible for receiving response from the real  Windows interfaces and will be written in TAP interface.